# How do I use an int as an address for a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Heyo everyone,

Lets say I got a register SP, in which is stored some int (more specific in form of uint8_t).

Now I want to use that int as an address for a pointer.

How exactly would I do that? I've searched nearly everywhere and didn't find a solution...

Comment: By casting like `(int*)hoge`?

Comment: `uint8_t* p = (uint8_t*)number;`. Or better make it `volatile`. If you know exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not something you want to do under normal circumstances, since it can easily cause undefined behavior if you don't know what you're doing.

But you can do something like this:

```
uint8_t address;
// Do something to address
char *ptr = (char*)address;
```

or if you want to skip an intermediate pointer:

```
uint8_t address;
// Do something to address
char c = *(char*)address;
```

Change `char` for whatever type you want.